# How to perform export action from rails_admin with Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sidekiq, rails-admin

I have a Rails 4.2.9 app that uses rails_admin gem to manage resources. The owner uses admin panel heavily and he would like to generate reports. The feature works locally but on staging and production I get `504 - gateway timeout`.

I guess the problem is that a lot of objects is generated and therefore, the request takes too much time. That's why I would like to delegate the export action to background job. The problem is however, that I cannot find where the export action is performed in a code and I do not which part I should wrap in a worker. The only part that has something to do with exporting is located in `rails_admin/application_controller.rb` but I guess that's not it:

```
def log_info
  params_to_log =
    params.except(:authenticity_token).merge(current_user_id: current_user.try(:id)).to_s
  Rails.logger.info("Generating admin report: #{params_to_log}")
end

def _authenticate!
  log_info if action_name == "export" && request.method == "POST"
  instance_eval(&RailsAdmin::Config.authenticate_with)
end
```

I did some research on it and it seems like a common problem, but I was unable to find a solution. If you can answer my question or suggest better solutions, I would be extremely grateful.